# Updating computed properties in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Are computed properties suppose to live update? I have this computed property:

```
fullName: (->
  firstName + " " + lastName
).property('firstName lastName')
```

When typing into the `firstName` or `lastName` fields, the computed property doesn't update until I rerender the page. Is this intended behavior? If so, how can I trigger an update? I've attempted to use an observer, but it doesn't even trigger:

```
nameChanged: (->
  alert "Triggered!"
).observes('firstName lastName')
```

The only time it goes off is when I rerender the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **specify the properties as comma separated list**:

```
fullName: (->
  firstName + " " + lastName
).property('firstName', 'lastName')
```

The same is true for observers:

```
nameChanged: (->
  alert "Triggered!"
).observes('firstName', 'lastName')
```

I did the same mistake some months ago :-)

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling it was something simple like that. For anyone else who finds this answer, it turns out you don't even need the observer. You can get the live updates with the computed property alone.